# pyInstaller build executable only

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I want to use the one folder mode of pyInstaller but I don't want to collect all the dependencies every time.

Most of the time I can reuse all the dependencies it has packaged previously I only need the executable, and I think I'd save 10~20 minutes on my build if I could just stop as soon as the .exe file is built.

I know about the -F flag to package all dependencies in a single executable, but this is not what I'm looking for.  I just want pyInstaller to stop before the packaging step.

I want the build to stop right when it might output:

```
WARNING: The output directory "XXX\dist\XXX" and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED!
```

Answer (score 1):

Haza! It only took two years to find the answer - and I've never seen this addressed directly anywhere else:

Once you have a .spec file you can run pyinstaller with the spec file as the target.

make the collect step conditional and it will not happen each time!
https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html